# Doxygen document structure with python superclass

Tags: python, python-3.7, doxygen, code-documentation, doxywizard

This is my first question in stack overflow:
This is my Python project structure:

superclass1:

1. module
2. class1 and it's modules
3. class2 and it's modules

superclass2:

4. module
5. class2-1 and it's modules
6. class2-2 and it's modules

How can I replace this type of structure in my documentation generated by Doxygen? I'm using doxywidzard and the configuration file associated.

Comment: Without more details, what replacement you intend, this can't be answered. I'm not too optimistic, changes are possible, since the standard configuration file has mostly on/off switches but no sequene set-up.

Comment: Besides the information as requested by guidot, please also specify the doxygen version used as well as the difference between the doxygen you use and the default doxygen configuration file.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.13